How to disable Spring (Boot) Security OAuth based on a config profile or specific property?
I'm integrating OAuth2 (Google as the OIDC provider) into an existing Spring Boot app that currently uses a simple DaoAuthenticationProvider. I've made the changes to get OAuth integration to work, but now I need to provide a configuration switch to turn it off in certain environments (fall back to using the old database-based authentication).
The configuration to use OAuth2 looks like this:
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: 1234567890-1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i0j.apps.googleusercontent.com
            client-secret: ABCDEF-1234-OU812_XYZZY

My @Configuration class for authentication looks like this:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class GoogleOIDCSecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    OidcUserService oidcUserService() {
        Set<String> scopes = Set.of(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
                );
        OidcUserService service = new OidcUserService();
        service.setAccessibleScopes(scopes);
        return service;
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain oidcFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, OidcUserService userService) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(this::configureAuthorization)
            .oauth2Login(c -> configureOAuth2(c, userService))
            .logout(this::configureLogout)
            ;

        return http.build();
    }

    protected void configureAuthorization(AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry authorize) {
        authorize
            .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.INCLUDE, DispatcherType.ERROR).permitAll()

            .requestMatchers("/*/*.js", "/*/*/*.js", "/css/**", "/lib/**", "/assets/**", "favicon.ico").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/", LOGIN_PAGE, INVALID_SESSION_PAGE, LOGOUT_PAGE).permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/foo/**").hasAnyRole(Roles.FOO)
            .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole(Roles.ADMIN)
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    private void configureOAuth2(OAuth2LoginConfigurer<HttpSecurity> oauthLogin, OidcUserService userService) {
        oauthLogin
            .userInfoEndpoint(endpoint -> endpoint.oidcUserService(userService));
    }
}

My first attempt at disabling it conditionally was to set client-id to empty in certain profiles and use @ConditionalOnProperty referencing that key. That fails with a validation exception saying client-id can not be empty. It seems that having anything under spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.* triggers auto-config of OAuth.
What I need to do is find a way to completely disable the auto-configuration for any OAuth clients, but only in certain profiles (or using a specific config property).

Why don't you put all of your OAuth2 configuration properties and beans into that profile?
# properties for all profiles here

---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile:
      - oauth2
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: 1234567890-1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i0j.apps.googleusercontent.com
            client-secret: ABCDEF-1234-OU812_XYZZY

@Profile("oauth2")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class GoogleOIDCSecurityConfiguration {
    ...
}

@Profile("legacy")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class LegacySecurityConfiguration {
    ...
}


It would probably be more useful to add the Gradle counterpart

Note that you can "auto opt-in" by setting this oauth2 profile active by default. With Maven, an activeByDefault profile is disabled if at least another profile is explicitly set (so you have to set it explicitly too if you want it with another profile). There might be an equivalent feature in Gradle. In your case, I'd set oauth2 profile active by default and I'd also define a legacy profile with the deps and conf for the older system, so that I'd only have one of the two confs and deps at a time.

We make use of "local" profile in all environments to allow easy overriding via application-local.yml (that's not going to change any time soon) so I don't think the trick of making oauth2 the default active profile will work.

Don't mix up Maven (or Gradle) and Spring profiles (local is a Spring profile). Have a closer look at the edited answer for the manual synchronisation between Maven and Spring profiles. Also note that each of this Maven profiles can be used "locally": oauth2 by activating no Maven profile (or with explicit activation) and legacy only with explicit activation (disabling oauth2, unless explicitly activated too, but why would one do that?)

I'm removing the Maven part of the answer since it's not directly relevant to answer the question. Interesting info, but I feel it's confusing an otherwise useful answer. I also fundamentally don't like needing to build separately for different environments. Build once, deploy many.

Sad that I got you confused, because it would probably be preferable that you have only one set of dependencies on the classpath at a time (and this requires some tweaking of the build system). The best way to disable a Spring Boot starter is actually to remove it from the classpath: no more transitive dependencies and no more auto-configuration.

Good catch on the csrf.dissble() call. That was a copy+paste mistake when writing the new OAuth2 config class. I removed it from the code in the question.

How do I make it "conditional on property" instead of using a profile?
